# How to use this BLDC and know more about it?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I have this BLDC I removed from a CD Drive.
I want to use it. Just for playful reasons. But I don't know what to make of it. Where to get started with on the Internet. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are fun to play with and a good introduction to BLDC technology.

Technically it is a 3 phase BLDC motor with 9 stator arms and 12 magnet poles, probably 'Star' wound, with analog Hall sensors. If it came from a standard size (5.25") CDROM drive then it is probably rated for 12V (but will run on less) and draws less than 1A in normal operation.

To drive it properly you need a BLDC controller. You can try to make one with a dedicated sensored controller chip [like I did](http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/sensored.html), but getting the wiring right is tricky (25 different different ways it could be connected, and only 2 are correct!). Alternatively just use a standard 'RC hobby' brushless ESC, and solder the ESC's phase leads directly to the windings (no need to connect the Hall sensors).

For even more fun you can try [rewinding](http://www.bavaria-direct.co.za/info/) it and replacing the Ferrite 'ring' magnet with [Neodym](https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/block-magnets-neodymium/block-magnet-5mm-5mm-1mm_Q-CDM48-G) magnets for more power.

If you do an Internet search for 'brushless CDROM motor' you should find many examples of driving them with an Arduino etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a brushless DC motor in itself – that's just the stepper motor-alike *part* of a BLDC motor.

The other half is the motor controller that sits on the PCB at the other end of the flat cable, which converts the DC to appropriately timed waveforms for the different coil circuits, based on desired speed/torque, position and other constraints. It typically has a closed loop control mechanism that incorporates the currents flowing through the coils and/or e.g. a hall effect sensor to observe the rotational state.

That means the project you're up for is designing an ESC – not a starter's project in itself, but luckily there's plenty of literature on motor control, and you'll certainly find something there on how to design ESCs for BLDC motors.